Is there a way to connect two programs output/input in linux?
I have two programs (p1 and p2), and I need to connect the p1 output to p2 input, and the p2 output to p1 input. Is there a way to do this?
The 'why' is because I have two programs that will play a game, so the first program will do a move and wait to receive a move from the other program and so on. The end of execution will be when  the first program exit with signal 0 or 1. The program p1 will always be the same, but the p2 will change over every iteration.
I need to do this in linux terminal, because the programs p1 and p2 can be (and probably will be) executed in different languages, like p1 will be c++ executable and p2 will be a python script.

Try named pipes (mkfifo).

@choroba  How I use this?

You can use the socat utility:
socat -v exec:p1 exec:p2

The -v is optional and shows the chatter back and forth for your debugging and enjoyment.

Fun, I had completely forgotten socat! But today I don't use them longer (I prefer ssh;-)... Not always installed, doable simply under shell... Even bashcould resonably replace netcat wth /dev/tcp in a lot of cases.

This is a common task for posix shell!!
As I daily repeat: shell is more an execution environment, than a programming language!
Intended for running other tasks and make them communicate with each others and/or log thems!

I need to connect the p1 output to p2 input, and the p2 output to p1 input

For this, I wrote two little programs that use STDERR for showing logs and communique by a simple ping-pong protocol by using STDIN/STDOUT:

ping.sh: send ping, wait for an answer, then log waited time.

#!/bin/bash
while :;do 
    sleep 1
    echo ping
    ping=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    read -r answ
    elap=00000$(( ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} - ping ))
    printf >&2 '%.5f %s\n' ${elap::-6}.${elap: -6} "$answ"
done


pong.sh: wait for a request, send pong as answer, then log waited time.

#!/bin/bash
while swait=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
        read -r req; do 
    echo pong
    elap=00000$(( ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} - swait ))
    printf >&2 '%.5f %s\n' ${elap::-6}.${elap: -6} "$req"
done

Then now:
1. By using named fifo (shell POSIX compatible):
This work same by using and POSIX compatible shell, tested unded bash, dash, busybox and ksh.
mkfifo namedFifo
./ping.sh < namedFifo | ./pong.sh > namedFifo 

0.00009 pong
1.00146 ping
0.00005 pong
1.00115 ping
0.00030 pong
1.00136 ping
0.00042 pong
1.00166 ping
0.00006 pong
^C

... Which could be 1. run in both way, 2. presented differently:
./pong.sh < namedFifo | > namedFifo ./ping.sh

2. By using coproc (bash only):
coproc ./pong.sh && ./ping.sh <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}

( Care, there are two ampersands: &&!! )
[1] 3872333
1.00060 ping
0.00030 pong
1.00189 ping
0.00009 pong
1.00210 ping
0.00007 pong
1.00121 ping
0.00019 pong
1.00156 ping
0.00006 pong
1.00121 ping
0.00006 pong
^C

Then, don't miss to close coproc's I/O in order to terminate them:
exec {COPROC[1]}>&-
exec {COPROC[0]}<&-

[1]+  Done                    coproc COPROC ./pong.sh

Same in the other way:
coproc ./ping.sh && ./pong.sh <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}

[1] 3895594
1.00140 ping
0.00008 pong
1.00179 ping
0.00006 pong
1.00101 ping
0.00004 pong
^C

exec {COPROC[1]}<&- ; exec {COPROC[0]}<&-

5.82724 
[1]+  Broken pipe             coproc COPROC ./ping.sh

Note: As Ctrl+C did stopped foreground pong.sh, ping.sh sent his log (whith an empty request) when I closed his input (exec {COPROC[1]}<&-) just before dying, when I closed his output (Broken pipe).
3. By using socat (SOcket CAT):
A suggeted by that other guy's correct answer
The advantage of using socat is that you could monitor traffic between the two programs by using -v switch:
socat -v exec:./ping.sh exec:./pong.sh 

> 2024/04/29 08:14:53.000359829  length=5 from=0 to=4
ping
< 2024/04/29 08:14:53.000359976  length=5 from=0 to=4
pong
1.00138 ping
0.00025 pong
> 2024/04/29 08:14:54.000361356  length=5 from=5 to=9
ping
1.00143 ping
< 2024/04/29 08:14:54.000361564  length=5 from=5 to=9
pong
0.00049 pong
^C

Where

lines prepended by > or < are socat log about resp. 1st command (ping.sh) or 2nd command (pong.sh),
lines containing only the word ping or pong are resp. ping.sh's or pong.sh's stdout, duplicated by socat in order to be shown on terminal, while sent to other command and
lines containing a float and the word ping or pong are resp. ping.sh's or pong.sh's stderr.

This is usefull for testing purpose and other labs operation, but as

socat is not installed by default on many distribution and
this method implie a subsequent unneeded stage (task, process, memory usage and other footprint),
this should not be used in production.

Monitoring?
There is a lot of way for monitoring what's happens in the two process you run:
My lighter scripts:

ping_nolog.sh: send ping and wait for an answer.

#!/bin/bash    
while :;do 
    sleep 1
    echo ping
    read -r answ
done


pong_noLog.sh: wait for a request and send pong as answer.

#!/bin/bash
while read -r req; do 
    echo pong
done

socat
Of course, as seen, socat seem to be the simplier
socat -v exec:./ping_noLog.sh exec:./pong_noLog.sh

> 2024/05/01 16:42:42.000007900  length=5 from=0 to=4
ping
< 2024/05/01 16:42:42.000008167  length=5 from=0 to=4
pong
> 2024/05/01 16:42:43.000010867  length=5 from=5 to=9
ping
< 2024/05/01 16:42:43.000011030  length=5 from=5 to=9
pong
> 2024/05/01 16:42:44.000014393  length=5 from=10 to=14
ping
< 2024/05/01 16:42:44.000015246  length=5 from=10 to=14
pong
> 2024/05/01 16:42:45.000017132  length=5 from=15 to=19
ping
< 2024/05/01 16:42:45.000017438  length=5 from=15 to=19
pong

But his output seem buggy on my host as every nanoseconds begin by a variable number of 0 and none end by 0 like auto trimed fractional part are left padded by 0... As I don't use them anymore, from a long time ago, I won't go further.
strace
strace --timestamps -e write ./ping.sh < namedFifo | ./pong.sh > namedFifo

17:02:08 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=521617, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
17:02:08 write(1, "ping\n", 5)          = 5
17:02:09 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=521634, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
17:02:09 write(1, "ping\n", 5)          = 5
17:02:10 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=521653, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
17:02:10 write(1, "ping\n", 5)          = 5
^C
strace: Process 521616 detached

./ping_noLog.sh < namedFifo | strace -e write ./pong_noLog.sh > namedFifo

strace -ewrite -f ./ping_noLog.sh < namedFifo | strace -ewrite -f ./pong_noLog.sh > namedFifo  

tee
You could duplicate output of each tool, in order to be able to read them entirely:
./ping_noLog.sh < namedFifo | tee ping.out | ./pong_noLog.sh > namedFifo 

./ping_noLog.sh < namedFifo | ./pong.sh | tee pong_noLog.out > namedFifo 

./ping._noLogsh < namedFifo | tee ping.out | ./pong.sh | tee pong_noLog.out > namedFifo 

perl
logThisPerl() { 
    perl -MPOSIX -MTime::HiRes -pe '
        BEGIN{$|=1;$txt=shift @ARGV;};
        my ($epoch,$musec)=split("\\.",sprintf("%.9f",Time::HiRes::time()));
        printf STDERR "%s.%s %s: %s",
            strftime("%a %d %b %T",localtime($epoch)),$musec,$txt,$_;
      ' "$1"
}

< namedFifo ./ping_noLog.sh | logThisPerl ping | ./pong_noLog.sh | logThisPerl pong  >namedFifo

Wed 01 May 16:52:59.149785042 ping: ping
Wed 01 May 16:52:59.149988890 pong: pong
Wed 01 May 16:53:00.151473045 ping: ping
Wed 01 May 16:53:00.151597977 pong: pong
Wed 01 May 16:53:01.153644085 ping: ping

bash and some others
As perl is not installed everywhere, and because this could be done by bash whith help of sed, GNU date, tee and paste ( and ps, ls, xargs and kill to terminate properly ;-):
logThis() { 
    local name=$1 fd pid cmd
    exec {fd}<> <(:) # Open a unnamed FD
    tee >(
        sed -ue 's/.*/now/' |
            stdbuf -i0 -o0 date -f - "+%a %d %b %T.%N $name:" >&$fd
    ) >(
        paste -d\  /dev/fd/$fd - 1>&2
    )
    # Kill pids before closing FD
    while read pid cmd; do
        /bin/ls -l /proc/$pid/fd/* 2>&1 |
            grep -q fd/$fd\  &&
            case $cmd in 
            bash ) ps --ppid $pid fwho pid |
                    xargs kill ;;
            *)  kill $pid ;;
        esac
    done < <(ps --ppid $$ fwho pid,cmd)
    exec {fd}>&-     # Close unnamed FD
}

< namedFifo ./ping_noLog.sh | logThis ping | ./pong_noLog.sh | logThis pong  >namedFifo  

Wed 01 May 16:59:12.117362965 ping: ping
Wed 01 May 16:59:12.117448897 pong: pong
Wed 01 May 16:59:13.119008938 ping: ping
Wed 01 May 16:59:13.119121684 pong: pong
Wed 01 May 16:59:14.122044766 ping: ping
Wed 01 May 16:59:14.122135863 pong: pong


If you've got Bash 4.0 (released in 2009), and the data going from p2 to p1 is textual (no ASCII NUL characters), line-oriented, and low in volume (no more than kilobytes per second); then you could possibly do what you want with a Bash coprocess.  Try this Shellcheck-clean code:
#! /bin/bash -p

coproc { p1 | p2; }

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
done <&"${COPROC[0]}"


See the Coprocesses section of the Bash Reference Manual for information about Bash coprocesses.  Coprocesses were introduced in Bash 4.0.
The loop reads lines from the output of the coprocess (which is the output of p2) and writes them to the input of the coprocess (which is the input of p1).


Avoid bash loop!! (Have a look at my answer:-)

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub,  your coproc solution is definitely a better way to do it.  I'm sorry that I didn't think of it.

There are several options using a fifo.
With one fifo:
mkfifo fifo
tail -f fifo | p1 | p2 > fifo &

With two fifos:
mkfifo fifo1
mkfifo fifo2
tail -f fifo1 | p1 > fifo2 &
tail -f fifo2 | p2 > fifo1 &

A reason to use 2 fifos could be, that it is possible to add something in the stream for both p1 and p2.

Why did you use  tail?

tail -f keeps the stream open. Otherwise, if you do an echo "extrainput" > fifo, the fifo will close.

Why not simply p1 < fifo | ... ?

Try it. cat < fifo & and then echo a >fifo and echo b>fifo versus the tail -f version.

No, simply: ./ping.sh <namedFifo | ./pong.sh >namedFifo, have a look at my answer!

Your answer works, if you write the scripts yourself. If you have existing programs, like cat in my suggestion to test, or nroff if you dislike cat, it will simply not work. With the tail -f, it will continue to read. Try it with existing programs instead of your own script.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What's problem with cat?? Jiust tried now: cat < namedFifo | > namedFifo ./ping.sh work fine!? Note: cat < namedFifo | > namedFifo cat work too, but it's not very relevant...

I think you're wrong in that: There are no reason to run both process in background! There are only 1 process to run in background. the second should be run in foreground!!
